# Replace a string dynamically in Python

Tags: python, string, scipy

I have mathematical functions of multiple variables written in strings; these have the following conventions of notation for the independent variables:

Example:

```
f_sym_st="(sin(x0))**2+exp(x1)*cos(x2)"
```

I use these in different calculations. In order to use scipy's minimize routine following
conventions for x is needed

```
f_opt_st="(sin(x[0]))**2+exp(x[1])*cos(x[2])"
```

I use

```
f_opt_st=f_sym_st.replace("x0","x[0]").replace("x1","x[1]").replace("x2","x[2]")
```

which works but I am looking something more dynamical. What if f_sym comes from another script and has, e.g., 21 independent variables?

"IDEA":

```
for i in range(0,21,1):#end of loop should also be variable
    f_sym_st=f_sym_st.replace("xi","x[i]")# obviously iteration does not work in strings
```

f_opt_st=f_sym_st

This is an Example - basically I would like to know if there is a way to replace strings dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function from the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) library:

```
In [10]: import re

In [11]: f_sym_st = "(sin(x0))**2+exp(x1)*cos(x2)"

In [12]: f_opt_st = re.sub(r"\bx(\d+)", r"x[\1]", f_sym_st)

In [13]: f_opt_st
Out[13]: '(sin(x[0]))**2+exp(x[1])*cos(x[2])'
```

The pattern `r"\bx(\d+)"` matches a word boundary followed by the letter `x` and then a sequence of digits.  The parentheses around `\d+` causes the digits to be saved as a group. The group is referenced in the replacement string as `\1`.

If you want to lower the index by one, you could change the replacement string to `r"x[\1-1]"`.  E.g.

```
In [56]: s = "x1*sin(x2) + x10"

In [57]: re.sub(r"\bx(\d+)", r"x[\1-1]", s)
Out[57]: 'x[1-1]*sin(x[2-1]) + x[10-1]'
```

Because this is just a string substitution, it doesn't simplify `1-1` to `0`.

If you don't want all those `-1`s in there, you'll probably not use `re.sub`.  Instead, you could do something like the following, in which `re.findall` is used to find the indices that are used in the expression:

```
In [132]: s = "x1*sin(x2) + x10*cos(x2)"

In [133]: indices = sorted(set(int(n) for n in re.findall(r'\bx(\d+)', s)), reverse=True)

In [134]: indices
Out[134]: [10, 2, 1]

In [135]: t = s[:]  # Make a copy of s.

In [136]: for ind in indices:
   .....:     t = t.replace('x' + str(ind), 'x[' + str(ind-1) + ']')
   .....:     

In [137]: t
Out[137]: 'x[0]*sin(x[1]) + x[9]*cos(x[1])'
```

If you prefer, the `for` loop could be changed to use the `format` method:

```
In [140]: for ind in indices:
   .....:     t = t.replace("x{0}".format(ind), "x[{0}]".format(ind-1))
   .....:
```

Comment: what if i wanted to lower the index by 1 ? Ex: x1 should become x[0] and so on?

Comment: I added some more variations to my answer.

Comment: I was wondering why you used "reverse" in `In[133]` - the "for" does not need this order - or do i misunderstand your intention? @WarrenWeckesser

Comment: I used `reverse=True` so that numbers more digits are processed first.  If `1` was processed before `10`, `x10` would be converted to `x[0]0`.  (See my comment to @klashxx's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Use format facilty:

```
for i in range(0,21,1):
    f_sym_st=f_sym_st.replace("x{0}".format(i),"x[{0}]".format(i))
```

Comment: Reverse the range, otherwise `x10` becomes `x[1]0`.